# Fazer div ficar dentro de outra

Tags: html, css

Sou bom em HTML mas de ontem pra hoje algo vem quebrando minha cabeça e até agora não resolvi! Quero o seguinte resultado (editado no PS):
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
mas, como está ficando:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Aqui meu código:

```
<div style="width:400px;height:400px;position: relative">
<div style="width:400px;height:400px;position: absolute">
    <div id="bg">
            <div style="transform:rotate(10deg);"></div>
            <div style="transform:rotate(25deg);"></div>
            <div style="transform:rotate(40deg);"></div>
            <div style="transform:rotate(55deg);"></div>
            <div style="transform:rotate(70deg);"></div>
            <div style="transform:rotate(85deg);"></div>
            <div style="transform:rotate(100deg);"></div>
            <div style="transform:rotate(115deg);"></div>
            <div style="transform:rotate(130deg);"></div>
            <div style="transform:rotate(145deg);"></div>
            <div style="transform:rotate(160deg);"></div>
            <div style="transform:rotate(175deg);"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>


<style>
html{background:#222;}
body {width:800px;height:400px;background:#333;margin:0 auto;}
#bg div {
border-bottom:1px solid #AD9268;
position: absolute;
width: 500px;
height: 2px;
margin: auto;
bottom:0;top:0;
left: -15px; right: 0;
}
#bg {
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
border-radius: 50%;
width: 465px;
height: 465px;
margin-top: -20px;
margin-left: -20px;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jovem é só vc colocar `overflow:hidden` na primeira `div` que vem por fora de todos os elementos, tb precisa fazer um ajuste na largura passado de `400px` para `450px` de largura!

Veja como fica:

```css
html {
    background: #222;
}

body {
    width: 800px;
    height: 400px;
    background: #333;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#bg div {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #AD9268;
    position: absolute;
    width: 500px;
    height: 2px;
    margin: auto;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: -15px;
    right: 0;
}

#bg {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 465px;
    height: 465px;
    margin-top: -20px;
    margin-left: -20px;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:450px;height:400px;position: relative; overflow: hidden;">
    <div style="width:400px;height:400px;position: absolute">
        <div id="bg">
            <div style="transform:rotate(10deg);"></div>
            <div style="transform:rotate(25deg);"></div>
            <div style="transform:rotate(40deg);"></div>
            <div style="transform:rotate(55deg);"></div>
            <div style="transform:rotate(70deg);"></div>
            <div style="transform:rotate(85deg);"></div>
            <div style="transform:rotate(100deg);"></div>
            <div style="transform:rotate(115deg);"></div>
            <div style="transform:rotate(130deg);"></div>
            <div style="transform:rotate(145deg);"></div>
            <div style="transform:rotate(160deg);"></div>
            <div style="transform:rotate(175deg);"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```